# Html video tag blinking when Setting new source?

Tags: javascript, html

I have video tag in my page it source will change for every 5 sec, After setting new source the video tag blinks (in between end of old source and new source setting )

Comment: In the `Elements` panel(Developers toos) ?

Comment: No on video tag only

Comment: That is default(normal) behaviour...

Comment: Is there any possibility to overcome that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting a new `src`, create a new video tag, wait for it to be ready, and then hide the old video and show the new one at the same time in its place.  You can then destroy the old element.

Comment: I thought that I did wrong solution and after 1 week of solution is ready I recall that I can ask this question on stackoverflow. And I see the solution the same :) Omg ))

Comment: I have 3 videos, 1st - invisible, static - the purpose to set height and width of div. 2nd and 3rd works as carousel, they are absolute, just increment z-index when switch to another source.